# Category and Subcategory send data for edit Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Hi everyone I am making a CRUD module for categories and sub categories using laravel ...
The rules I have set are:
-I can create categories at level 0
-I can create sub categories by selecting a level 0 parent

There is a problem...
When I enter the edit.blade.php page I would like that when I enter a default subcategory he would select me the category he is a child of.

CategoryController

```html
public function edit($id)
    {
      $categories = Category::with('children')->where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
      $category = Category::find($id);
        return view('backend.category.edit')->with([
          'categories'  => $categories,
          'category' => $category
        ]);

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $category = Category::find($id);
      
      $category->name = $request->name;
      $category->slug = Str::slug($request->name, '-');
      $category->parent_id = $request->parent_id;
      $category->status = $request->status;
      $category->save();
      return redirect()->route('category.index')->withSuccess('You have successfully edited a Category!');
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```html
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>Category</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('category.update',$category->id) }}" method="POST">
                      @csrf
                      @method('PUT')
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                      <label class="col-form-label text-md-right col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $category->name }}">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                      <label class="col-form-label text-md-right col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Slug</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" id="slug" class="form-control" name="slug" value="{{ $category->slug }}" readonly>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                      <label class="col-form-label text-md-right col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Parent ID</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                        <select class="form-control selectric" name="parent_id">
                          @if($category->parent_id == 0)
                          <option selected value="0">Level 0</option>
                          @foreach ($categories as $category)

                          <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>

                          @endforeach
                          @else
                          <option value="0">Level 0</option>
                          @foreach ($categories as $category)
                          @if($category->parent_id === $category->id)
                          <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                          @else
                          <option selected value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                          @endif

                          @endforeach
                          @endif
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                      <label class="col-form-label text-md-right col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Status</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                        <select class="form-control selectric" name="status">
                          <option value="1">Active</option>
                          <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                      <label class="col-form-label text-md-right col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Category</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
```

Comment: Shouldnt `@if($category->parent_id === $category->id)` be interpreted the other way around? You want the `selected` attribute when the category_id and parent_id match right?

Comment: I would just like to see the top category saved in the database associated with the record. For example cat1->sub cat1 cat2->subcat2. I would see when i open subcat1 (edit.blade) the parent selected